# Not able to write the spark dataframe to s3 bucket

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

hi in my spark Application i am reading a csv file from s3 bucket. and after trying to write the same file to s3 but throwing out error.

i am authentication aws s3 with aws keys.

here is the code for the spark application

```
package com.spark.example

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j.{Logger,Level}

object S3IOTest {
  def main (arg: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().
      master("local").
      appName("demoApp").
      getOrCreate()
    val accessKeyId = System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
    val secretAccessKey = System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", accessKeyId)
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", secretAccessKey)
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    println("****************************")
    println(s"spark session create: $spark")
    println("****************************")
    val data = spark.read.option("header",true).option("inferschema",true).csv("s3a://examplelake/sparkinput/*.csv")
    data.show(5)
//    data.write
//      .mode("overwrite")
//      .csv("s3a://publicexamplelake/sparkoutput/out/")
    data.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").save("s3a://publicexamplelake/sparkoutput/out/")
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

and the error log i am attaching.

```
****************************
spark session create: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@1e6b9a95
****************************
+-----------------+-------------------+-----+
|DEST_COUNTRY_NAME|ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME|count|
+-----------------+-------------------+-----+
|    United States|            Romania|    1|
|    United States|            Ireland|  264|
|    United States|              India|   69|
|            Egypt|      United States|   24|
|Equatorial Guinea|      United States|    1|
+-----------------+-------------------+-----+
only showing top 5 rows

20/04/28 00:41:09 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.BasicDiskValidator.checkStatus(BasicDiskValidator.java:32)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createTmpFileForWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ADataBlocks$DiskBlockFactory.create(S3ADataBlocks.java:811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.createBlockIfNeeded(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.<init>(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1098)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:987)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVFileFormat.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
20/04/28 00:41:09 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
20/04/28 00:41:09 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job d130d4c0-7a73-4ad9-a00c-864414087847.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.BasicDiskValidator.checkStatus(BasicDiskValidator.java:32)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createTmpFileForWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ADataBlocks$DiskBlockFactory.create(S3ADataBlocks.java:811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.createBlockIfNeeded(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.<init>(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1098)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:987)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVFileFormat.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at com.spark.example.S3IOTest$.main(S3IOTest.scala:31)
    at com.spark.example.S3IOTest.main(S3IOTest.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.BasicDiskValidator.checkStatus(BasicDiskValidator.java:32)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createTmpFileForWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ADataBlocks$DiskBlockFactory.create(S3ADataBlocks.java:811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.createBlockIfNeeded(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.<init>(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1098)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:987)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVFileFormat.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at com.spark.example.S3IOTest$.main(S3IOTest.scala:31)
    at com.spark.example.S3IOTest.main(S3IOTest.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.BasicDiskValidator.checkStatus(BasicDiskValidator.java:32)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createTmpFileForWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ADataBlocks$DiskBlockFactory.create(S3ADataBlocks.java:811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.createBlockIfNeeded(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.<init>(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1098)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:987)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVFileFormat.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.BasicDiskValidator.checkStatus(BasicDiskValidator.java:32)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createTmpFileForWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ADataBlocks$DiskBlockFactory.create(S3ADataBlocks.java:811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.createBlockIfNeeded(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.<init>(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1098)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:987)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVFileFormat.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am running this script in my local machine using maven project.
please comment if you need any information.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it looks like Spark is failing to `createTmpFileForWrite` in the stack trace.  I recommend checking `hadoop.tmp.dir` to ensure it exists and is writable.  Before uploading, the S3A writer will buffer the data to disk, by default, in a subdirectory of `hadoop.tmp.dir`.  See [the S3A Client Configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#General_S3A_Client_configuration) for additional System properties that may help.  Fiddling with fs.s3a.fast.upload.buffer may help.

Comment: Can we change these while writing to s3?